# match and print multiple columns from two files

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I have two files what i need to do is find common lines based on column1 in both the files and if the match then write to a new file col1(common between two files) file1col2 and file2col2

file1:

```
col1                         file1col2
10:100000525-100001560(+)    0.971465226620556
10:100001724-100002618(+)    0.940918504451204
10:100002725-100002970(+)    0.946592696189412
10:100003104-100004184(+)    0.736305487299153
10:100004450-100005051(+)    0.70823022283736
10:100005158-100005876(+)    0.969728923411704
10:100006075-100007551(+)    0.855411430976336
10:100007764-100009009(+)    0.274219271261146
10:100009146-100011362(+)    0.927057564779308
10:100011583-100011887(+)    0.883431738847249
```

file2

```
col1                         file2col2
10:100000525-100001560(+)    0.943385996874889
10:100001724-100002618(+)    0.981929023174133
10:100002725-100002970(+)    0.955549170283206
10:100003104-100004184(+)    0.736440826679551
10:100004450-100005051(+)    0.689045711238636
10:100005158-100005876(+)    0.964995337925152
10:100006075-100007551(+)    0.873411848029685
10:100007764-100009009(+)    0.37719743446494
10:100009146-100011362(+)    0.943862343124518
10:100011583-100011887(+)    0.902915705720447
```

desired output

```
col1(common between two files)  file1col2   file2col2
10:100000525-100001560(+)   0.971465227 0.943385997
10:100001724-100002618(+)   0.940918504 0.981929023
10:100002725-100002970(+)   0.946592696 0.95554917
10:100003104-100004184(+)   0.736305487 0.736440827
10:100004450-100005051(+)   0.708230223 0.689045711
10:100005158-100005876(+)   0.969728923 0.964995338
10:100006075-100007551(+)   0.855411431 0.873411848
10:100007764-100009009(+)   0.274219271 0.377197434
10:100009146-100011362(+)   0.927057565 0.943862343
10:100011583-100011887(+)   0.883431739 0.902915706
```

Comment: `join --header file1 file2` seems like it should work here - what is your question exactly?

Comment: @steeldriver join needs both file should have same number of lines right? (plz correct me if  i am wrong) here file1 has 500 lines and file2 ~ 2000 lines and it also has un common lines

Comment: They need to be sorted in the order of the common field, but do not need to have the same number of lines AFAIK: by default, only pairable lines are output, although you can include unpairable lines using the `-a` command line option if you wish. See `man join`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***join*** + ***awk*** solution:

```
join --header file1 file2 | awk 'NR>1{ $2=sprintf("%1.9f",$2); $3=sprintf("%.9f",$3) }1' > result.txt
```

---

```
cat result.txt
col1 file1col2 file2col2
10:100000525-100001560(+) 0.971465227 0.943385997
10:100001724-100002618(+) 0.940918504 0.981929023
10:100002725-100002970(+) 0.946592696 0.955549170
10:100003104-100004184(+) 0.736305487 0.736440827
10:100004450-100005051(+) 0.708230223 0.689045711
10:100005158-100005876(+) 0.969728923 0.964995338
10:100006075-100007551(+) 0.855411431 0.873411848
10:100007764-100009009(+) 0.274219271 0.377197434
10:100009146-100011362(+) 0.927057565 0.943862343
10:100011583-100011887(+) 0.883431739 0.902915706
```

---

***Details***:

- *join* `--header` option - treat the first line in each file as field headers, print them without trying to pair them
- `NR>1` - start processing from the 2nd record (`NR` - number of the current record), i.e. - skip *header* line
- `sprintf("%1.9f",$2)` - format argument `$2` (the 2nd column) as float number with 9 decimal places

Comment: can you please walk me over your script

Comment: @sbradbio, yes, see my details

Comment: this helps appreciate it, how do i edit it in case i do not have any header?

Comment: @sbradbio, version without headers: `join file1 file2 | awk '{ $2=sprintf("%1.9f",$2); $3=sprintf("%.9f",$3) }1' > result.txt`

Comment: awesome again appreciate it